# check if attribute value already exists

Tags: product

I want to check if attribute value already exists programatically.

i created a unique attribute in magento say regnum , now i want to see if for any regnum value if there already exists product or not ,

can u please guide me how to do this ? i am bit new and can not figure out how to do it

Comment: regnum is dropdown or text attribute?

Answer (score 1):

- Write a [shell script](http://inchoo.net/magento/php-shell-scripts-for-magento/)
- Create  a product Collection  which  give list products which have
  regnum fields
- group this collection by grouByAttribute('regnum')

`require '[Your_Magento_DIR]/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app("admin");
umask(0);
$collection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('renum');
$collection->groupByAttribute('renum');
$renumValues=$collection->getColumnValues();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('//your product  id here');
```

if **dropdown** attribute

```
<?php if($_product->getRegnum()): ?><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('regnum'); ?><?php endif ?>
```

if **text** attribute

```
<?php if($_product->getRegnum()): ?><?php echo $_product->getRegnum(); ?><?php endif ?>
```